sum_over_time on query_range vs query different value return
I have two APIs for Prometheus.
First:
api/v1/query?query=sum_over_time(metric_name{label_id="20000"}[49666s:1s] @1727675266)

The above query aims to get the total sum of every 1-second sample until the start of the day. e.g., the current timestamp is 1727675266, and it will start from now to the start of the day, which is 49666 seconds.
Second:
api/v1/query_range?query=sum_over_time(metric_name{abel_id="20000"} [15s:1s]) or vector(0) &start=1727625600&end=1727712000&step=15s

The above query aims to get the total sum of every 15 seconds range with 1 second resolution from end of today to the start of today. It will return the list of sum data every 15 seconds.
I am trying to validate my query results and found out that the total sum for each sample in query_range does not equal the total sum from the query. By right, these two query sum values should be the same/close, right? Or why I am getting the two different sum values? Like big value difference. Am I missing some logic?

Other then your queries having very different time ranges (query_range - full day, query - only some 13 hours) result should be as you expect, as far as I can tell.

@markalex, Yes I don't know why atm. Even though the query range was selected for full-day, there is no sample for the future so I expected to return 0 which is vector(0). From now to the start of the day is 13 hours and each query uses 15 seconds time range with 1 second resolution. So it should return the same/ close value.
